# Ideapad 300 suspend not working on 16.04

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 16.04

I was unable to get my Ideapad 300 running properly with 14.04(no wifi and lan not functioning), so I decided to try LTS 16.04.

Everything works well untill I tried going to suspend mode. Either when I closes my laptop lid or I click **suspend**. The screen just when off and did nothing to suspend. There is no way for me to recover the laptop from the state unless I press the power button long enough to shut it down and then power it back again.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems that it is a 4.4.0 kernel bug, installing 4.4.8 solves the problem.
You can either wait for a 4.4.0 kernel fix, or install the 4.4.8 kernel.

**I recommand waiting for 4.4.0 fix**, but i installed 4.4.8 and i've seen no problem whatsoever.

Execute following commands in order to install 4.4.8 kernel:

**On 32-bit**

Download

```
cd /tmp
$ wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_i386.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_i386.deb
```

Install

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
```

**On 64-bit**

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
```

Install

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
```

Source : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125

Comment: Does 4.5 carry the same fixes that were introduced with 4.4.8? I just went to 4.5 from 4.4.0 and am still having this problem, although the random hard freezing has stopped...

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a bug. Follow here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125